# ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: django, model

I have a model Comment:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

When I try to create a comment I get an AttributeError:

```
ipdb> usr = User.objects.get(pk=1)
ipdb> usr
<User: admin>
ipdb> Comment.objects.create(owner=usr)
*** AttributeError: 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'username'
ipdb> usr.username
u'admin'
ipdb>
```

Comment: I don't now if it has to do with it, but you don't accept null in text field, so it would fail creation anyways.

Comment: I tryed also owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True) without success

Comment: I meant this: `text = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)`

Comment: this sadly doesn't change anything to my error

Comment: I've just tried and it work. Let me analyze this.

Answer (score 4):

I had this traceback, too:

```
'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute my_attribute
```

I found the solution:

```
Comment.user # Access on class level: does raise the above error

comment.user # Access on instance: this works!
```